# ASP.NET chart control background image: URL is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts, background-image, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm trying to set a background image on my ASP.NET (built-in) chart control to an image located on: http://www.example.com/images/logo.png
I can access this image in my browser.

But I'm getting this error:

> 'http:/www.example.com/images/logo.png' is not a valid virtual path.

Notice how 1 `/` character is removed from the path after the protocol name.

My code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chartPriceHistory" runat="server">
</asp:Chart>
```

I tried this:

```
chartPriceHistory.BackImage = "http:\/\/www.example.com/images/logo.png"

chartPriceHistory.BackImage = "http://www.example.com/images/logo.png"
```

Both scenarios throw the same error.

What else could I do?

Comment: That's not a virtual path. Can you store the image locally and do `~/img/...`?

Comment: Hmm..you're right...strange as IntelliSense and the documentation state that I could add an URL. Anyway, thank you! Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: I saw the same, path can be absolute or virtual but didn't see any examples of virtual. If you can, add a sample working path to a comment. (If it's really different than the ex in the answer.)

Comment: I meant to say i didn't see any examples of absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a virtual path. Can you store the image locally and do `~/img/...`?